# If Jquery Kendo popup window closed, Jquery code after "close statement" is not executing

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem in Jquery Kendo Popup window. I want to run some code after closing Kendo Popup window. But when I place "close" statement, the code behind the "close" statement is not executing. How can I achieve this?

My sample code is below

```
 alert('Popup is closing.')
 window.parent.$("#qm_modal").data("kendoWindow").close();
 alert('After closing popup.')
```

Is it due to window.parent or anything else which stops my code to execute.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you check the developer console? My guess would be that an exception is thrown when trying to call the `close()` method, which interrupts the JS execution.

Comment: There is no error in console. I checked It.

Comment: What is `window`? It could by clashing with [the global variable window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) . Rename it to `popupWindow` or something.

Comment: @GaloisGirl It is the window keyword. It will not clash with code. It is working ok in application. but now here I want to execute below code of close statement.

Comment: Are you trying to close the popup in a parent from within an iFrame? Are both pages in the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var window = $("#qm_modal").data("kendoWindow");
window.close();
alert('After closing popup.');
```

https://www.telerik.com/forums/closing-a-window-on-button-click